# How do I restrict mysql UPDATE to just the row I'm dealing with inside a for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I have a web app that will send btw 1 and 20 notification emails every time a user submits a form.  The user will already be in a group (they'll have a `groupid` number) and all people in that group will get an notification email.

NOTE:  I am sending emails using PHPMailer and SMTP via Amazon SES.

BACKGROUND: If there are 10+ emails, it would take about 5 seconds to send before showing user the "successful form submission" message.

So I've decided to send the email in the background to improve UX, using a cron job that will run every minute.

I created a simple additional mysql table called "cron_email_notify" with just fields for:

- `groupid` (id of the group the user is in)
- `sent` (0 by default, will be updated to 1 after cron-job runs)

In the cron script that will run probably every minute, I search for all `groupid`s that have `sent` set to 0 (meaning they still need to get notification emails).  I loop thru and send the emails and update `sent` to be 1 after each loop.

The issue is that if more than 1 user from the same group submit the form before the cron-job runs, there will be 2 (or more) entries with the same `groupid` and `sent` set to 0.

If I then update `sent` to 1 for that groupid using the code below, it will update ALL rows with that `groupid`.  And only one notification email will be sent when maybe 3 or 4 should have been sent.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE cron_email_notify SET sent = 1 WHERE groupid = ? ");
$stmt->execute([$poolid]);
```

What is proper way to ONLY update the `groupid` for the row that I'm looping through?  Is it as simple as adding "LIMIT 1" to the end of the UPDATE query? Or is there a more proper way to do it?

Comment: What is the difference of mails if two users of the same group do a call before the cron is execute ?

Comment: Very valid question.  They are exactly the same, but the agreement is that each person in the group gets a notification email EACH time someone in the group submits. So if 5 people submit within the same minute (which is possible), they will get 5 notification emails so that they know exactly 5 people submitted.   With that said, I am still wrestling with just letting them get one notification email even if 5 people submitted.   Would eliminate the problem in my question, but still need to think about whether I want to do that or not.

Comment: Let me some minutes (I'm currently in reunion) I'll suggest you an update of your table to handle this case :)

Comment: Do my answer helped you ? :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you do not have a primary key set on your table. Add a new column named e.g. mailId  and make it the primary key with auto increment. Each time you update a row, use that column to define which row you want to update

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE cron_email_notify SET sent = 1 WHERE mailID = ? ");
$stmt->execute([$mailID]);
```

Also you might want to keep track on the date/time the mail was sent, for example by replacing sent for sentTime, make it an integer (if you want to use UnixTime) or a DateTime. Once the mail is sent, you set the value to the current time. Mails that have not been sent will have the default value, or NULL set (by which you can find them)

Another option is to check if the combination groupid with sent = 0 already exists in the table. If so, don't insert... why send this group two mails?

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey.  For your last question, see my comment under my original question.  The fact that you both asked about it is making me lean towards NOT sending multiple emails. Could just annoy people. One a minute is probably enough.  Otherwise, thanks for your primary key suggestion. I knew it would be something obvious. I will go that route if I decide to send multiple emails

Answer (score 1):

Your table `cron_email_notify` isn't complete for me, you can't identify which user edited the group for example, or when exactly he edited it (imagine you have some issues to send emails and you have to resend them manually later)

You could use this table schema
`cron_email_notify(id, user_id, date_modified, date_send, send)`

- id INT autoincrement
- user_id foreign key to the user table to identify who edited the group
- date_modified datetime DEFAULT NOW() at which date the user edited the group
- date_send at which date the mail is send
- send boolean as you said if the mail notifications has been send

Why don't store the group id ? The user_id is enough, you can retrieve the group_id from the user table. Moreover if someday you change a user of group you'll have to modify the `cron_email_notify` table too

You could do a sql query like that to retrieve users to notify by modification of a user

```
SELECT users_to_notify.*, cen.date_modified
FROM cron_email_notify cen
INNER JOIN user user_modifier ON user_modifier.id = cen.user_id
INNER JOIN user users_to_notify ON users_to_notify.group_id = user_modifier.group_id
WHERE cen.send = 0
ORDER BY cen.date_modified
```

Be carefull, log the results you may do some PHP formating of the rows
I don't know exactly your sql schema please adapt this query to your needs.
With this query you can add to your notification mails some context of which user modified your group, at which date